# How to read the entire value of a double using cin?

Tags: c++, double

```
long double m;
cout << "enter double: "; cin >> m;
cout << "m = " << m <<endl;
```

Input:

enter double: 1.546640625

Output:

m = 1.54664

I have to convert into a binary with point, and when I read numbers like 2.359375000

Output:

m = 2.35938

And it works, but I think the problem is the zero in 1.546640625

Comment: It did read the entire value. The problem is in how you display it.

Comment: there are more information now

Comment: The problem is not the zero. The value will be stored fully (subject to the ability of the data type to accurately store that value). The problem is that the output is limited to a small number of decimal places by default, but you can change that as the answers below indicate.

Comment: I'm trying to take the decimal part of m and don't works `long double m, p_decimal, ;
    int p_entera; p_decimal = (long double)m - p_entera;`

Comment: p_entera stores `p_entera = (int)m;`

Comment: seems to be [working](http://ideone.com/oOSqR6) for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have read the whole value of the double. The problem is with the cout. It by default rounds the value to 6 digits after the decimal point.

To set the precision cout uses, use `setprecision` from `<iomanip>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long double d;
    cin >> d;
    cout << setprecision(10) << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See his edit. This does indeed fix the problem now, but on different input (where you don't know the precision) it won't work. You're basically relying on the fact that that his number has 10 digits. And if you set the precision to more, it won't be the same number. - http://ideone.com/hc81nt

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am simply showing how to increase the precision, never stted 10 will always be enough. What I tried to point out is that it is not the input that causes the problem. I totally agree with J99's comment to the question and believe the answer I give is what he is looking for.

Comment: @freinn what is p_entera? I mean how do you compute it?